# Looking for a solution that is essentially the opposite of PHP's cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

My title does pretty well to explain what I'm looking for, but a bit more details. We currently have a service that sends out data to URL using cURL. Now the next phase of our implementation we need to have a URL on our server that accepts incoming POST data, specifically data that will be in XML format.

Does anyone know of any solutions to handle this scenario? I know once we get the data we can use SimpleXML to parse it down into the out going format we need. In this case we are essentially the middleware for processing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you need to do is accept the parameters (or XML in this case) as `$_POST` variables and then print out a response.  Once you get the XML, you can set it to a variable just like any other field you get from `$_POST` and process it.  Once you've done your work, simply print out a message and that is the response the user will get back when they call your API.

If you are returning a certain type of data, like XML, you can add a header in there to tell PHP to output the response as that type.

```
// STORE THE POST INTO A VARIABLE THAT YOU CAN WORK WITH
$xml = $_POST['body'];

// DO SOMETHING WITH THE XML

// SEND A RESPONSE BACK TO THE CLIENT
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8');
print '<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
  <status>Accepted</status>
</response>
</xml>';
```

Comment: So this would store the xml stream into a string?

Answer (score 1):

The solution would depend on how the POST data is getting to you.

If the data is coming in a POST field then PHP will populate the `$_POST` superglobal and you can access the data via the named POST field:

```
//postdata: xml=<myxml>…</myxml>

$xml = $_POST['xml'];
```

If the data is coming as a raw POST however you will need to read from the [`input` stream](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.input) :

```
//raw postdata: <myxml>…</myxml>

$xml = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Once you have the data in a PHP variable you can do with it as you wish:

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xml);
```